# Typescript/Angular 12: cast custom object into params-object

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use the `fromObject` key of `HttpParamsOptions` to cast an custom object into a params-object.

This works:

```
foo(): void {
   const testObject = {
     id: 123;
     name: 'test';
     someExample: 'test';
   }
   const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: testObject });
   ...
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
export interface SearchParams {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  someExample: string;
}

foo(testObject: SearchParams): void {
   const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: testObject });
   ...
}
```

`fromObject` does not work if I define the object type.

Error: TS2322: Type 'SearchParams' is not assignable to type '{ [param: string]: string | number | boolean | readonly (string | number | boolean)[]; }'.   Index signature is missing in type 'SearchParams'.

Any ideas how to solve this? I'm using Angular 12.

Comment: The constructor of `HttpParams` takes a parameter with an index signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easyest way:

```
   const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: {...testObject} });
```

The error occur because your parameter type `SearchParams` doesn't match with the fromObject type that is:

```
    fromObject?: {
        [param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
    };
```

Basically `fromObject` param accept any literal object.

So you can achieve the same result in some different ways. For example...

Declaring a literal object (as you did too):

```
    const testObject = {
      id: 123;
      name: 'test';
      someExample: 'test';
    }
    const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: testObject  });
```

Declaring an object copying from another using the spread operator:

```
    const myObject = { ...testObject };
    const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: myObject  });
```

Or casting as `any` type:

```
   const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: testObject as any });
```

From the [typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) about the `any` type:

> The any type is useful when you don’t want to write out a long type
> just to convince TypeScript that a particular line of code is okay.

Or changing the `SearchParams` interface to be compatible with the `fromObject` param type:

```
  export interface SearchParams {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    someExample: string;
    [param: string]: string | number;
  }
    
  foo(testObject: SearchParams): void {
    const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: testObject });
  }
```

Comment: What about if I want to pass a complex object that have a parameter of object type. Can that be passed?

Comment: Agree that the spread operator resolves this issue.